# getExternalFilesDir returns one of sdcard and emulated randomly; how to pick?

Tags: android, file, storage, external, sd-card

In my app, I download certain files from internet and store them in the ExternalStorage location returned by the function `getContext().getExternalFilesDir(null)`.  This saves my file in the location `/sdcard/Android/data/mypackage/files/HERE`.

Now, I try to open an image from that location using this:

```
InputStream imgStream = new FileInputStream(getContext().getExternalFilesDir(null)+additionalPathToImage);
```

But, I get a file not found error.  I found out that in the above piece of code, the getExternalFilesDir returns some other location `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/mypackage/files/HERE`.

I am wondering why the same method would return different file locations when called from the same App, albeit different activities.

The image was rendering fine when I loaded from assets directory.  I had to migrate for some reasons to external storage.  So why is it messed up?! Aren't those locations the same?!

Comment: The locations are the same as you have discovered. Links. Linux is your friend. Having said that I never saw getExternalFilesDir() return different paths.